# Kendo Grid with rowTemplate and reorderable binds data in wrong column

Tags: kendo-grid

I've come across an issue when using rowTemplates and switching on the reorderable gridOption in kendo grid.

Link to example:
http://dojo.telerik.com/@antman/AzEvi

To reproduce,
 1. Run it
 2. Drag the Ship Country column to be the first column (before Id)
 3. Page right

Note that the data has been bound in the original column order (Id, Ship Country). The data hasn't sync'ed with the Column re-order.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing this problem, I got a response from Telerik Support with a work-around:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/column-reordering-row-templates-for-grids#YhCaITvAaEax2uWJ6iEakA